Why write $f(1)$ separately from the integral, while finding whether a series is bounded or not with integrals?

In the picture, attached, I have pointed out the step which I cannot understand with an arrow. Here, please explain why instead of taking the whole integral from $0$ to $\infty$ we separately add $f(1)$ and the integral from $1$ to $\infty$. Had I taken the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ instead of adding $f(1)$ separately, the logic should still hold (from the diagram), then why is that not done in the example?

You should try to compute $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}, dx$, this should answer your question.

$\int_1^{2}f(x)dx >f(2)$, $\int_2^{3}f(x)dx >f(3)$ etc.

@noam.szyfer I get it that it's uncomputable, but how can we generalise this in theorem 9(in the pic attached)? It's not computable for this function, but it may be computable for some other function.

Theorem 9 as stated is already quite general. Or are you asking what argument would prove Theorem 9 rather than just a special case of it?

@J.G. By generalise I mean to say a theorem that is suited for universal application for all functions...like in the example given, f(x) has the y axis as its asymptote, hence integration of f(x) from 0 to infinity is not possible, but there can be some other example where f(x) is defined at x=0, hence in that case we can just integrate f(x) from 0 to infinity instead of adding f(1) seperately.

For what it's worth, whether $f(1)$ has to be manually included depends on whether $\int_0^1f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ exists and is finite, not whether $f(0)$ exists and is finite. For example, we get the former - not the latter, but that's unimportant - if $f(x)=\frac{x^{-1/2}}{1+x}$.

@J.G. yes so basically we need to add take f(1) seperately or just include it in the whole integral from 0 to infinity depending from function to function, right?!

Q: Why do we separately add $f(1)$ and the integral from $ 1 $ to infinity, instead of taking the whole integral from $ 0 $ to infinity?
The integral from $ 0 $ to $ 1 $ diverges:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx \to \infty \quad \text{(doesn't converges).}$$
As a result, the entire integral from $ 0 $ to infinity also diverges:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx \to \infty \quad \text{(doesn't converges).}$$
Therefore, we can't conclude that $ S_n < 2 $ by including the integral over the range from $ 0 $ to $ \infty $. Instead, we consider the convergent part of the integral from $ 1 $ to infinity:
$$\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} \, dx$$
and add $ f(1) $ separately. If you look at the graph, you'll see that the area under the curve for $ 0 < x < 1 $ is not finite.
Here’s a plot on Desmos:


Ok, so depending on the function, I can choose to either add f(1) seperately to the integral from 0 to infinity(if the y-axis is a asymptote for f(x)), or if the integral from 0 to 1 of f(x) is bounded then I can combine them to just write integration of f(x) from 0 to infinity. Am I right?

@aditya, Yes, in mathematics, you need to use some information wisely. For the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ you can easily write integration of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $\infty$.
